How to get the error message in full when displayed like in the picuture
I get an error like this in a mobile application I'm helping to make, but I have know idea how to get a full error message when it's displayed like this.
does anyone have an idea how to
image displaying error
I want the full description error message

You want to show the Toast message in full screen, right?

If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, its toast is limited to two lines of text and shows the application icon next to the text. Be aware that the line length of this text varies by screen size, so it's good to make the text as short as possible or consider using different method for handling errors.
